# Is it possible to use the Dexter WiFi Sensor with Robot C?

Tags: nxt, wi-fi

My wife bought me a Mindstorms NXT system a few years ago and I bought a [Dexter WiFi sensor](http://www.dexterindustries.com/manual/wifi/) for it, by the time I got a chance to work with it, I found out the sensor had been "retired" and that the sample drivers no longer worked with the new versions of Robot C?

Has anyone managed to edit the drivers to a working state with Robot C 4?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [dexter website](https://www.dexterindustries.com/manual/wifi/), there is sample robotC code which means, yes you can use the Dexter WIFI sensor with robotC. Maybe there are robotC libraries for it in the download section on that website.

[This](http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=18429&sid=789110c10cb98198ae7806938b97b761) forum thread also loosley states that you can use the Dexter WIFI sensor with robotC

Hope this helped.